# How to arrange picture, equation and chemical formula in a grid-style layout?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, chemfig, tabu

For an optical representation, I need to arrange a picture, an equation and a chemical formula in a grid-style layout. However, it's much harder than I thought.

First I tried `tabu`, but the vertical alignment of the right column looks horrible.
[image: First attempt with tabu]

Second, I tried `TikZ` which gives me a nice layout, but the moment I replace the `dummytext` with the `\chemfig` command, it gets complety messed up.
[image: Second attempt with TikZ]

Are there any simple solutions for this? I know I could convert the equation and the formula to individual pictures and include them using `\includegraphics`, but I then each change requires several recompilations.

Here's the corresponding MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu, multirow}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%% for the whole Tikz stuff
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, shapes.misc, matrix, positioning}

\tikzstyle{fotobox}=[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text centered, text width=0.6\textwidth]

\tikzstyle{textbox}=[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=0.3\textwidth]

\begin{document}

%% load the pictures from the web, if necessary
\IfFileExists{./infrarotPlot.pdf}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./infrarotPlot.pdf http://pgfplots.net/media/tikz/examples/PDF/infrared.pdf}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(diagramm)[fotobox, ] at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{infrarotPlot} \\ Nice diagram};

\node(mathe)[textbox, right=of diagramm.north east, anchor=north west, text height=0.2\textheight]
{$E = m c^2 + 1$};

\node(chemie)[textbox, right=of diagramm.south east, anchor=south west, text height=0.5\textheight]
{Dummytext for chemical formula};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\begin{tabu}{X[l,m] X[c,m]}
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{infrarotPlot}} & $E = m c^2$ \\
 & \chemfig{[7]H_3C-CH(-[6]CH_3)-[1]CH_2-CH_2-[1]CH_3}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps text height is  on a good choice to set the height. Try `minimum height` and see if that is better (not at pc, so cannot test). How exactly do you want things to be aligned inside the boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are three ways of doing it.

The first one uses ordinary tabulars, nested. The only trick is to move the baseline of the image to half of its height using

```
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
```

The second one uses multiple columns and requires no tricks.

The third one uses `tikz`. Since `\chemfig` cannot be used inside a tikz node (because the formulas are tikz pictures themselves), we first typeset the formula outside of the tikz picture into a `savebox` and then use this box inside the tikz node.

```
\newsavebox\formula
\savebox\formula{\chemfig{[7]H_3C-CH(-[6]CH_3)-[1]CH_2-CH_2-[1]CH_3}}
...
\node(chemie)[...] {\usebox\formula};
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=15mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu, multirow}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%% for the whole Tikz stuff
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, shapes.misc, matrix, positioning}

\tikzstyle{fotobox}=[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text centered, text width=0.4\textwidth]

\tikzstyle{textbox}=[
    rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=0.3\textwidth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}&
\begin{tabular}{c}
$E = m c^2$\\[5ex]
\chemfig{[7]H_3C-CH(-[6]CH_3)-[1]CH_2-CH_2-[1]CH_3}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\newpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\columnbreak

\vspace*{\fill}

$E = m c^2$
\vfill

\chemfig{[7]H_3C-CH(-[6]CH_3)-[1]CH_2-CH_2-[1]CH_3}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{multicols}
\newpage

\newsavebox\formula
\savebox\formula{\chemfig{[7]H_3C-CH(-[6]CH_3)-[1]CH_2-CH_2-[1]CH_3}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(diagramm)[fotobox, ] at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image} \\ Nice diagram};

\node(mathe)[textbox, right=of diagramm.north east, anchor=north west]
{$E = m c^2 + 1$};

\node(chemie)[textbox, right=of diagramm.south east, anchor=south west]
{\usebox\formula};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I finally opted for the third method with the `savebox` inside the `tikzpicture`, works nicely.