# How to set axis label background color to opaque?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

For a presentation, I want to overlap two images with the second one covering the first one completely.
The second one is created using `pgfplots`. I can set the background of the `axis` area to `white`, but not the `label` area.
See here:[image: Image Overlap]
How can I set the `xlabel` and `ylabel` areas to opaque as well?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy, backgrounds, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%% load the pictures from the web, if necessary
\IfFileExists{./infrarotPlot.pdf}
{}
{
    \write18{wget -O ./infrarotPlot.pdf http://pgfplots.net/media/tikz/examples/PDF/infrared.pdf}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.95,draw opacity=1]

\node(image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{infrarotPlot}};  %\raisebox{-0.5\height}

\node(image2)[anchor=north west] at (-7,-4)
{
\begin{axis}[
width=0.7\textwidth,
height=0.8\textheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xlabel={Dimensionless number $\zeta$ (-)},
x axis line style={opacity=0.9},
ymin=0,
ymax=2000,
ylabel={Resulting pressure $\Sigma p$ (bar)},
y axis line style={opacity=0.9},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.73,0.97)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
%% Formula 1
\addplot[blue, domain=0:1, samples=101]
{2000*(1 - x^2)};
\addlegendentry{Formula 1};
\end{axis}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `* axis line style` properties do not seem to accomplish this.
Also, the positioning is quite clumpsy. I tried to use `\raisebox` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342904/77950), but it gives an error, so does not seem to work inside `tikzpicture`.

---Comment on @torbjørn-t 's answer---

Thanks for the hint to the `at` key. However, using your first solution it gives me this, where some parts of the underlying image (some of which are highlighted by red squares) are still visible!
[image: imageOverlap2]
Isn't there a way to just define the background of the *whole* plot instead of each element one by one?

Comment: Just edited again, not sure why I took the `backgrounds` route in the previous revision.

Comment: Thanks. Using your second approach, it works as expected.
Still wondering though why there's no global background option for the`axis` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're after

```
ylabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
xlabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
```

If you want the ticklabels as well, add a similar `ticklabel style`, as in the code below (commented). (There are also `xticklabel style` and `yticklabel style` if you just want to affect one axis.)

Don't put an `axis` inside a `node`, use the `at` (and optionally the `anchor`) key. As for the positioning, you need to explain what you want to do.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.95,draw opacity=1]

\node(image1) [inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};  %\raisebox{-0.5\height}

\begin{axis}[
at={(image1.north east)},anchor=north east,
width=0.7\textwidth,
height=0.8\textheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xlabel={Dimensionless number $\zeta$ (-)},
x axis line style={opacity=0.9},
ymin=0,
ymax=2000,
ylabel={Resulting pressure $\Sigma p$ (bar)},
ylabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
xlabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
%ticklabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
y axis line style={opacity=0.9},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.73,0.97)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left},
]
%% Formula 1
\addplot[blue, domain=0:1, samples=101]
{2000*(1 - x^2)};
\addlegendentry{Formula 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## A different route

Add image, add a white fill above, then add `axis`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.95,draw opacity=1]
\node (image1) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
\fill[white,opacity=0.8] (image1.south east) rectangle (image1.north west);
\begin{axis}[
at={(image1.north east)},anchor=north east,
width=0.7\textwidth,
height=0.8\textheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xlabel={Dimensionless number $\zeta$ (-)},
ymin=0,
ymax=2000,
ylabel={Resulting pressure $\Sigma p$ (bar)},
legend style={at={(0.73,0.97)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left},
]
%% Formula 1
\addplot[blue, domain=0:1, samples=101]
{2000*(1 - x^2)};
\addlegendentry{Formula 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```